# Issue with Apple Pay / Stripe integration

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, stripe-payments, applepay

I have followed Stripe's documentation and Example App on integrating Apple Pay.

In the handlePaymentAuthorizationWithPayment method, under createTokenWithPayment, I am getting the error:

> Error Domain=com.stripe.lib Code=50 "Your payment information is formatted improperly. Please make sure you're correctly using the latest version of our iOS library. For more information see https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios ." UserInfo=0x170261b40 {com.stripe.lib:ErrorMessageKey=Your payment information is formatted improperly. Please make sure you're correctly using the latest version of our iOS library. For more information see https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios ., NSLocalizedDescription=Your payment information is formatted improperly. Please make sure you're correctly using the latest version of our iOS library. For more information see https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios .}

Anyone know how to resolve this? I am using the latest Stripe library.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I know what happened here.  Leaving this up in case it helps anybody.

When I initially set up Stripe / Apple Pay into my app, I kept getting numerous errors when  I attempted to implement `STPTestPaymentAuthorizationController`.  I found the exact problem described here ([Stripe payment library and undefined symbols for x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25830285/stripe-payment-library-and-undefined-symbols-for-x86-64?newreg=a05c941717c049f1a98eb785a822b82e)).

I replicated the solution defined above by commenting out part of Stripe's code, which maybe (?) produced the `Error Domain=com.stripe.lib Code=50` error.

I fixed this by not using `STPTestPaymentAuthorizationController` at all, just replacing that with `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController` in `#DEBUG` mode.

**tl:dr** Not completely sure why STPTestPaymentAuthorization didn't work; avoided situation completely  by running PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController with my iPhone and Stripe dashboard in test mode.

Comment: Hi May, if I pay using Apple Pay with my Touch ID with Stripe in Test Mode, is it not going to charge my card ?

Comment: @SaiJithendra Correct, it won't charge your card even though the transaction will appear successful on your phone.

Answer (score 5):

This little bit of RnD helped me. Digging into the [CustomSampleProject](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/tree/master/Example) provided by Stripe themselves, ApplePayStubs works pretty well when the **STPCard** is recognized when the delegate

```
- (void)paymentAuthorizationViewController:(PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *)controller
                   didAuthorizePayment:(PKPayment *)payment
                            completion:(void (^)(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus))completion
```

of **PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate** is called. The sample code here checked if the code was run in debug that is for ApplePayStubs, the **(PKPayment *)payment** in the delegate is converted to a **STPCard** and is launched to the **STPAPIClient** for **STPToken** generation. Following is the body of the above mentioned delegate:

```
#if DEBUG // This is to handle a test result from ApplePayStubs
if (payment.stp_testCardNumber)
{
    STPCard *card = [STPCard new];
    card.number = payment.stp_testCardNumber;
    card.expMonth = 12;
    card.expYear = 2020;
    card.cvc = @"123";
    [[STPAPIClient sharedClient] createTokenWithCard:card
                                          completion:^(STPToken *token, NSError *error)
    {
        if (error)
        {
            completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatusFailure);
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                        message:@"Payment Unsuccessful! \n Please Try Again"
                                       delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
            return;
        }
    /*
     Handle Token here
     */
                                            }];
}
#else
[[STPAPIClient sharedClient] createTokenWithPayment:payment
                                         completion:^(STPToken *token, NSError *error)
{
    if (error)
    {
        completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatusFailure);
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                    message:@"Payment Unsuccessful!"
                                   delegate:self
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        return;
    }
    /*
     Handle Token here
     */
}];
#endif
```

This worked for me. With ApplePayStubs (on Simulator) and without them (on Device) Hope this Helps :)